# Bootstrap 5 dropdown shadow issue on IOS

Tags: dropshadow

How can I remove this box shadow in IOS device, it's the bootstrap 5 navbar's dropdown and its perfect in Android device.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  You can start by [edit]ing this question and adding a [mre] of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Please include all the necessary details to answer the question into your question. Please don't ask people to go to random websites.